# Modify Request to a POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 2 app and is getting errors when I try to redirect to the following method;

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Transaction]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Payment payment, PaymentApplication paymentApplication, string exchangeId, bool manual, int firstPaymentId, int? exchangeEventId, bool addOnly)
    {
```

because it has POST property. Is there anyway I can modify the request header to 'simulate' a POST and go to the correct action??

Comment: You should try to accept some answers on your previous questions. That drives interest (at stackoverflow.com) in answering your future questions.

Comment: can you provide more code? for example, code inside the Edit method? that would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot redirect to actions that require POST verb. Redirects are performed by the client browser using GET verb after the server sent a 301 status code to the new location.

Comment: @JamaicasFinest, the workaround is to use an HTML form or an AJAX that will directly POST to the target action. It is impossible with redirect.